# Make two search fields fill 100% width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

Wordpress and code rookie here. Website is www.chicagokaraokenight.com/wordpress.

On the homepage search widget, I'm trying to remove the keyword field, and make the Location and By Day field 100% of the width of the area on the same line. My theme has provided documentation on how to have one field remaining filling the width 100%, but not two fields. I've tried a variety of combos and can't figure it out. Please advise!

Here is the provided CSS:

```
.search_jobs > div.search_keywords {
    display: none;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_location {
display: none;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_categories {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: It has to work, check for typos there.

Comment: You mean that you'd like the two remaining fields to occupy 50% of the line each?

Comment: Avoid to use `!important`, it's a really bad habit to have.

Comment: The code above works, just not what I was trying to accomplish. The !Important was recommended by the Theme...why is it a bad habit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
.search_jobs > div.search_keywords {
  display: none;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_location {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_categories {
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

**Update:** Just found out that the divs of these fields have a margin-right of 3% each, which makes it impossible for us to have two divs of 50% width each in the same line. Easiest solution is to lower their widths a bit to compensate the margin, which would make the code be like this:

```
.search_jobs > div.search_keywords {
  display: none;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_location {
  width: 47% !important;
}

.search_jobs > div.search_categories {
  width: 47% !important;
}
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you!! I tried the 50% one before but it went on two lines (I guess because of the margin), but I hadn't tried the 47% thing. Genius!!

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark my answer as selected so it may help other people with similar problems :)

Comment: one quick additional question. On mobile, it shows up a little weird now. Do you recommend a plugin that allows me to define different CSS for mobile phones? Or do I just have to deal with it (i.e. sacrifice having the ability to do this for the weirdness on mobile?)

Comment: If you were a bit more experienced in CSS, I'd recommend you to have a look in media queries (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). But as this is not the case, I'd say that it's possible that there is a Wordpress plugin that does it, yes. :)